# qual a melhor forma de criar um cookie para o sistema de votação para usuário votar uma so vez

Tags: php

esse sistema a para classificação com estrelas está tudo funcionando mais queria somente criar um cookie para que usuario vote so uma vez a cada dia tentei de varias forma mais o cookie nao e gerado

```js
$(function(){
 var average = $('.ratingAverage').attr('data-average');
 function avaliacao(average){
  average = (Number(average)*20);
  $('.bg').css('width', 0);  
  $('.barra .bg').animate({width:average+'%'}, 500);
 }
 
 avaliacao(average);

 $('.star').on('mouseover', function(){
  var indexAtual = $('.star').index(this);
  for(var i=0; i<= indexAtual; i++){
   $('.star:eq('+i+')').addClass('full');
  }
 });
 $('.star').on('mouseout', function(){
  $('.star').removeClass('full');
 });

 $('.star').on('click', function(){
  var idArticle = $('.article').attr('data-id');
  var voto = $(this).attr('data-vote');
  $.post('votar.php', {votar: 'sim', artigo: idArticle, ponto: voto}, function(retorno){
   avaliacao(retorno.average);
   $('.votos span').html(retorno.votos);
  }, 'jSON');
 });
});
```

```css
.barra{width:150px; height:30px; background:#ebebeb; position:relative;}
.stars{position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%;}
.star{
 float:left; 
 width:30px; 
 height:30px;
 text-align:center; 
 position:relative; 
 cursor:pointer;
}
.star.full{background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fee24f, #f4bb2f)}

.bg{float:left;height:30px; width:30%; background:linear-gradient(to bottom, #fee24f, #f4bb2f);}
.starAbsolute{
 position:absolute; 
 top:0; 
 left:0;
 width:100%; 
 height:100%; 
 background:url(../starpng.png) top left no-repeat; 
 background-size:cover;
}
```

```html
<?php
 include_once "../Config.inc.php";
?>


<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
 <meta charset=UTF-8>
 <title>pagina teste</title>
 <link href="<?= BASE; ?>/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
                  <script  src="<?= BASE; ?>js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
                  <script  src="<?= BASE; ?>/js/avaliations.js"></script>
</head>

 <body>
<?php
 $id_pro =1;
 $pegaArtigo = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM `wc_app` WHERE id = $id_pro");
 $pegaArtigo->execute(array($id_pro));
 while($artigo = $pegaArtigo->fetchObject()){
  $calculo = ($artigo->pontos == 0) ? 0 : round(($artigo->pontos/$artigo->votos), 1);
?>

<span class="ratingAverage" data-average="<?php echo $calculo;?>"></span>
<span class="article" data-id="<?php echo $id_pro;?>"></span>

<div class="barra">
 <span class="bg"></span>
 <span class="stars">
<?php for($i=1; $i<=5; $i++):?>


<span class="star" data-vote="<?php echo $i;?>">
 <span class="starAbsolute"></span>
</span>
<?php 
 endfor;
 echo '</span></div><p class="votos"><span>'.$artigo->votos.'</span> votos</p>';
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
require 'environment.php';
global $config;
$config = array();
if(ENVIRONMENT == 'development') {
 $config['dbname'] = 'megaki';
 $config['host'] = 'localhost';
 $config['dbuser'] = 'system';
 $config['dbpass'] = 'system';
} else {
 $config['dbname'] = 'megakico_megaki';
 $config['host'] = 'localhost';
 $config['dbuser'] = 'megakico_system';
 $config['dbpass'] = 'system302573';
}

try {

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:dbname=".$config['dbname'].";host=".$config['host'], $config['dbuser'], $config['dbpass'], [PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"]);
}catch(PDOException $e){
 echo "conhexao ao banco de dados falhou".$e->getMessage();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Primeiro você deve entender quais são todas as possíveis opções que você tem a disposição.

## Cookies

É a opção mais simples de se utilizar. O seu script PHP irá definir um cookie no navegador do usuário com a data em que votou, e cada vez que ele visitar o site novamente você verificar se já se passaram 24 horas (ou o tempo desejado).

#### Vantagens

- É largamente suportado por todos os navegadores, sejam eles mais simples ou mais avançados.
- É um dos métodos mais simples de ser implementado, pois o dado fica no lado cliente e o servidor necessita apenas fazer uma verificação.

#### Desvantagens

- O usuário pode mudar de navegador e votar novamente.
- O usuário pode limpar os cookies do navegador e pode votar novamente.
- O usuário pode editar o valor do cookie, quebrando sua lógica facilmente.

## Local Storage

É uma opção para navegadores que tem suporte. O dado é armazenado no lado do cliente, assim como no caso dos cookies.

#### Vantagens

- Dispensa processamento do lado do servidor.

#### Desvantagens

- Assim como os cookies, pode ser manipulado facilmente pelo usuário.
- A lógica da votação vai ficar obrigatoriamente do lado do cliente, logo o usuário pode manipular facilmente isso para votar novamente.

## Armazenamento de IP

Você guarda o IP do usuário no servidor e verifica a cada vez se ele já atingiu o limite de votos diários.

#### Vantagens

- O usuário não consegue manipular facilmente o dado, podendo mudar de navegador e limpar cookies que a regra continua a mesma.
- Não há necessidade de se preocupar em suportar mais navegadores, pois mesmo se estiver com cookie desabilitado, a regra continua funcionando.

#### Desvantagens

- Maior custo de infra, pois terá que armazenar o IP e a data da última vez que votou.
- Se o usuário estiver em uma rede compartilhada, somente um deles vai conseguir votar, portanto quem estiver em LanHouses não vai poder votar.
- Se o usuário mudar seu IP, reiniciando seu Modem por exemplo, ele pode votar novamente.

## Conclusões

Nenhuma tecnologia é perfeita, e todas vão sofrer de alguma forma. Minha recomendação é que você utilize a técnica do armazenamento do IP, pois ela acaba sendo a técnica mais custosa, mas a que lhe garante a maior segurança. Obviamente a técnica do cookie também é bem vinda, pois os usuários normais geralmente utilizam apenas 1 navegador.

Por fim, você pode ainda optar por uma combinação de técnicas, armazenando o IP no servidor e enviando um cookie ao cliente. Desta forma você tem uma garantia um pouco maior que não está sendo burlado.

**Observação**: Estou considerando que você quer garantir que os usuários anônimos não votem duas vezes. Caso você esteja querendo verificar se um usuário logado já votou duas vezes, você pode simplesmente criar um campo a mais no banco de dados que armazene esta informação e se livrar de todos os outros problemas.

Comment: Lembrando que mais de usuário compartilha o mesmo endereço de IP, principalmente com o uso de CGNAT, ou seja não tem haver com LanHouses, mas sim com o próprio provedor que faz vários clientes terem o mesmo IPv4.

Comment: Inkeliz, não conhecia esta técnica de distribuição de IP. Obrigado por indicar.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

// Cria o cookie usuario só que irá durar 1 dia
setcookie('usuario', 'usuario@usuario.com', (time() + (1 * 24 * 3600)));


?>
```

Pronto, se o cookie existir, ele não pode votar, se não existir, ele pode votar.

Comment: E se eu entrar nas configurações do meu navegador e excluir os cookies existentes?

Comment: Caso você faça isso, o usuário burla-rá o sistema. Por isso é recomendado que para esse caso use um BD gravando um campo para isso

Answer (score 0):

Bom desconheço sistema de votação aberto (para usuários não cadastrados) que zele por fiabilidade dos dados.

Caso seja este o caso somente com uso de **cookies** ou dados no **localStorage** em ambos os casos podem ser facilmente burlados ou modificados quebrando a lógica do código.

No caso de usuários registrados (e assumindo o uso de sessão ou um estado não-stateless) o item a ser votado deve possuir entrada no banco de dados registrando algum identificador do usuário que **"votou"** e sempre ao realizar **votação** deve-se verificar se o mesmo já não realizou tal operação.

A primeira lógica seria enviar o **ID** do usuário más, visto que ao utilizar `javascript` este pode ser burlado por um usuário mal intencionado inúmeras vezes. Para contornar isto pode-se enviar um `tokem` criado durante o login e verificado antes de inserir.